# Laravel: relationship between Teams and Matches

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently making a small website where volley-ball `Teams` will play some `Matches`. Here is what I have for now:

`Match` model:

```php
class Match extends Model
{
    public function Team1() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'team_1');
    }

    public function Team2() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'team_2');
    }
}
```

For example, `$match->team1->name` works well.

`Team` model:

```php
class Team extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function Matches() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Match');
    }
}
```

But `$team->matches` gives this error:

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'matches.team_id' in 'where clause'`

Which is normal because Laravel tries to find a `team_id` field in database but there's actually two: `team_1` and `team_2`.

I'm thinking that relationships between my models might be wrong but I'm not sure.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the right relationship for the data structure you have, but there are two possible ways a team can have a match.

```
class Team extends Model
{
    public function matchesAsTeam1()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Match', 'team_1');
    }

    public function matchesAsTeam2()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Match', 'team_2');
    }
}
```

To get all matches in a single relation is slightly tricky, and requires knowing about the `->union()` method.

```
public function matches()
{
    return $this->matchesAsTeam1()->union($this->matchesAsTeam2());
}
```

This will get all matches where the team is either team 1 or team 2 of the match.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with eager loading. For example

```
App\Team::with('matches')->get();
```

will work to get the matches where that team is `team_1` but not the matches where that team is `team_2`. If you find yourself using these relations in the context of `->with('matches')`, `->has('matches')`, and `->whereHas('matches', function($subquery) {})`, this approach will prove problematic in my experience.

I might consider using a many-to-many relationship here, despite the fact that "many" in the second case is always 2. That would involve defining a `match_team` table:

```
Schema::create('match_team', function($table) 
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('team_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('team_id')->references('id')->on('teams');
    $table->integer('match_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('match_id')->references('id')->on('matches');
});
```

Then your relations end up being

```
class Team extends Model
{
    public function matches()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Match::class);
    }
}

class Match extends Model
{
    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
    }
}
```

If you do use that approach, you'll need to ensure that you enforce that each match has exactly 2 teams.

Comment: Just a warning -- it works, but not perfectly. For example, `App\Team::has('matches')` will not work (it'll only get matches as team 1). Likewise, eager loading (`App\Team::with('matches')->get()`) won't work properly. Unfortunately, I haven't found a good way around this.

Comment: Okay, thanks for sharing this because I was about to use eager loading into my project.